# Redirect to a site if referer is a specific site (htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess

Is it possible, to configure the `htaccess` file in a way, that a redirect to a certain site will happen, if the referer fits to another site? Kinda hard to explain, maybe it will get a bit clearer with an example:

I'm on the site `mysite.com`, click on a link and will be redirected to `mysite2.com`. If I just enter `mysite2.com`, it won't allow me to enter, since the desired way is to go there by link.

If I can make it any cleaner, just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in .htaccess at root of the second site.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://example.org/(.*)$
#or the path to the page with link: !^http://example.org/page.html$
RewriteRule $ http://other_site.org/wrong_referer.html [R]
```

This will redirect if the referer is wrong. However it is possible to send an incorrect referer, so this check is unreliable.